# Create dynamic peer connections with a java script class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, webrtc, event-listener

Hello I am trying to develop a dynamic web conference app. It should be possible that any number of participants can join the conference. For this purpose a RTCPeerConnection class should be created. The idea is that every time a user wants to join the conference a new object of the class will be created. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement the event listener from ontrack and onicecandidate into the class. Additionally, I get a reference error when I run the `setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer` function. I think this is because the ontrack function is missing.

```
class PeerConnection {

    constructor() {
        this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
        this.remoteStream = null;
        this.candinate = [];
    }

    createOffer() {

        console.log("offer from JS");
        this.connection.createOffer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
        }).then(async sdp => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
            if (this.connection.localDescription == null) {
                await this.connection.setLocalDescription(sdp);
            }
        });
    }

    createAnswer() {
        console.log("answer");
        console.log(answer);
        this.connection.createAnswer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
        }).then(async sdp => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
            //später
            await this.connection.setLocalDescription(sdp);
            //webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(sdp));
        });
    }

    async setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer(sdp) {
        console.log("remoteDescription Offer");
        console.log(this.connection);
        await this.connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).then((e) => {
            createAnswer();
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)

        })
    }

    async setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer(sdp) {
        console.log("remoteDescription Answer");
        await this.connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).catch((e) => {
            console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)
        })
    }



    this.connection.ontrack(e) {
        console.log("onTrack", e.streams[0]);
        this.remoteStream = e.treams[0];

    }

    this.connection.onicecandidate = function (e) {

      if (e.candidate != null) {
  
       // webSocket.current.send(JSON.stringify({
         // type: "candidate",
          //candidate: e.candidate
        //}));
        console.log("sendet Candidate", JSON.stringify(e.candidate));
      }
  
}


export { PeerConnection }
```

A part of App.jsx

```
mport { useEffect, useRef, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import User from "./User"
import { UserContextList } from './UserContext'
import { PeerConnection } from './connection'
import './App.css'

function App() {

  const textRef = useRef();

  const localVideoStream = useRef();
  const localAudioStream = useRef();

  const remoteVideoStream = useRef();
  const remoteAudioStream = useRef();

  const peerConnections = useRef([])

  async function getMedia() {
    const constraints = {
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    }
    console.log("getStream");
    await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => {
        console.log("stream", stream);
        localVideoStream.current.srcObject = stream;
        localAudioStream.current.srcObject = stream;

        localVideoStream.current.muted = true;
        localAudioStream.current.muted = true;

        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
          //console.log("user Media", stream);
          peerConnections.current[0].connection.addTrack(track, stream);
        })
      })
  }


  function createOffer() {

    peerConnections.current[0].createOffer();
  }


  function createAnswer() {

    peerConnections.current[0].createAnswer();

  }

  async function setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer() {
    let sdp = JSON.parse(textRef.current.value);
    peerConnections.current[0].setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer(sdp);
  }

  async function setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer() {
    let sdp = JSON.parse(textRef.current.value);
    peerConnections.current[0].setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer(sdp);
  }

  function setCandidate() {
    //later
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    peerConnections.current.push(new PeerConnection());

    getMedia();

  }, [])
return(
<div>
      <div className="memberContainer">
        <div className="member">
          <video ref={localVideoStream} autoPlay style={{
            height: `${250}px`,
            width: `${250}px`,
            border: `solid ${1}px black`
          }}
          ></video>
          <audio ref={localAudioStream} autoPlay></audio>
        </div>
        <div className="member">
          <video ref={remoteVideoStream} autoPlay style={{
            height: `${250}px`,
            width: `${250}px`,
            border: `solid ${1}px black`
          }}></video>
          <audio ref={remoteAudioStream} autoPlay ></audio>
        </div> 
     </div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={createOffer} >offer</button>
      <button onClick={createAnswer}>answer</button>
      <button onClick={setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer}>setRemoteDescriptionOffer</button>
      <button onClick={setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer}>setRemoteDescriptionAnswer</button>
      <button onClick={setCandidate}>setCandidate</button>
      <br />
      <textarea ref={textRef}></textarea>
      <br />
</div>
```

I have searched the internet on how to implement an event listener in a class and unfortunately have not found anything. For this reason I don't know if it is the right idea to create such a dynamic connection.

Comment: I suggest you read the following web page to make your life easier.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation

Comment: Yes I have looked into it and I know how to make a connection or two connections. Each connection needs another RTCPeerConnection object. I want to create this dynamically and create as many connections as I want. Now to test about buttons later with a server

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution. It's trivial, but Java script is a new language for me.

So first of all, all attributes of a Java Script class must have a this. Also, the eventlistener of the class RTCPeerConnection must be implemented in a method of the class `PeerConnection`. This method must be called in the constructor of `PeerConnection`. Thus the class looks like this

```
class PeerConnection{

    constructor() {
        this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
        this.remoteStream = new MediaStream();
        this.userID = null;

        this.PCEventListener();
    }

    createOffer() {
        this.pc.createOffer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
        }).then(async sdp => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
            await this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);
        });

    }

    createAnswer() {
        this.pc.createAnswer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
        }).then(async sdp => {
    
            console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
            //später
            await this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);
        });

    }

    async setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer(sdp) {
        await this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).then((e) => {
            console.log(this.pc.remoteDescription);
            createAnswer();
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)
    
        })
    }

  async  setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer(sdp) {
    await this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).catch((e) => {
        console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)
    })
    }


    PCEventListener() {
        this.pc.ontrack = (event) => {
            console.log("on Track");
        }

        this.pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            console.log("ice candidate");
        }
    }
}
```